# Sitecore FakeDB Set Template Standard values

Tags: unit-testing, fakedb

I am working on unit tests. So I am using fake DB. I am trying to set template standard values. So I used below code.

```
Item newItem = db.GetItem(contextId);
var standardValues = newItem.Template.CreateStandardValues();

newItem.Template.StandardValues.Editing.BeginEdit();
newItem.Template.StandardValues.Fields["__Renderings"].Value = "Test"; // This line gives exception. It gives "its not in editing mode" exception.
newItem.Template.StandardValues.Editing.EndEdit();
```

While setting renderings value I am getting "**StandardValues is not in Editing Mode**".
Also I would like to know that is this the way to set standard value of template.
I am trying to get code coverage for below case

```
item.Template.StandardValues.Fields["__Renderings"].Value
```

Just giving you context about original code,  below is the original code

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Template.StandardValues.Fields[renderingsFieldName].Value))
{
  //Copying the Shared Rendering from template standard value to item's shared rendering
  item.Fields[renderingsFieldName].Value = item.Fields[renderingsFieldName].GetStandardValue();
}
```

Comment: This line of code: `newItem.Template.StandardValues.Add( .Fields["__Renderings"].Value = "Test";` doesn't actually compile, that is not how the `.Add` method works. What exactly are you trying to test, because there is very little value in unit testing Sitecore's own code, Sitecore should be doing that (yes I know ;))

Comment: @RichardSeal
Yes agreed, I have update that code line.
newItem.Template.StandardValues.Fields["__Renderings"].Value = "Test";
I want to just set the value for rendering, because it shows null in code base.
And in original code there is "if condition" based on that.
So I couldnt get 100% code coverage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Trial and Error, I found below approach to set the templates renderings in standard values. And it works for me. Hope It might works for others

```
 var standardValues = newItem.Template.CreateStandardValues();

 standardValues.Editing.BeginEdit();
 standardValues.Fields["__Renderings"].Value = "Test";
 standardValues.Editing.EndEdit();
```